# How to disable iptables from kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, iptables, sysctl

I'm famillar with `iptables -F` and other features of `iptables`. 

 I need to disable `iptables` from kernel, of course I prefer to disable from `sysctl` instead of recompiling the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your kernel uses modules for `iptables`, which is the case in most distributions, you can blacklist the base module; create a file named, for example, `/etc/modprobe.d/iptables-blacklist.conf`, containing

```
install ip_tables /bin/false
```

You can block other variants in a similar fashion (`ip6_tables`, `ebtables`, `nf_tables` etc.), or block `x_tables` to block `ebtables`, `iptables`, `ip6tables` and `arptables` in one go (but not `nftables`).

Comment: You might also want to disable `ip6_tables` in the same fashion. Better yet might be to disable `x_tables` and get rid multiple modules at one time.

Comment: Indeed, thanks @doneal24, I’ve added that to the answer.

Comment: Hm, are there advantages to use `install ip_tables /bin/false` over simply `blacklist ip_tables`?

Comment: @maxschlepzig `blacklist` doesn’t prevent the module being loaded as a dependency, so it’s ineffective in this case.

Comment: Note that `x_tables` may still be used by `nft_compat`, so blacklisting `x_tables` may make `iptables-nft` give errors like ``Couldn't load match `limit'`` on `-m limit`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621397/iptables-stopped-working-with-couldnt-load-match-stateno-such-file-or-direc/728000#728000 . Blacklisting only `ip_tables` resolved that for me.