# iptables stopped working with “Couldn't load match `state':No such file or directory”

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

This rule

```
-A INPUT  -i eth0  -p tcp -s 10.0.0.6/24 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 17828 -j ACCEPT
```

used to work just fine until recently on my iptables, but now seems to fail with the following message:

```
iptables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): Couldn't load match `state':No such file or directory
```

Might this be due to a system update? I can't figure out the issue here. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it might be due to a system update — iptables is being replaced by nftables, and the version of `iptables-restore` that you're running is using nftables. Please try running [iptables-legacy-restore](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Legacy_xtables_tools) instead, and tell us how that goes.

Comment: Yes it did work! Thanks! Should I really then migrate to the newer nf_tables?

Comment: Cool! I'll submit that as an answer, then — please mark it as accepted. And yeah, migrating to nf_tables is a good idea, as at some point, distros will dump the old iptables, forcing the migration on you. Better to do it on your terms, and your timeline :) Try iptables-translate, it can help you with the bulk of the transition.

Comment: In my case, I needed to run the command as an elevated user to have it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it might be due to a system update — iptables is being replaced by nftables, and the version of `iptables-restore` that you're running is using nftables. You should run [iptables-legacy-restore](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Legacy_xtables_tools) instead.

In the long term, it's better to migrate to nftables, because iptables is going to get deprecated and removed from distributions at some point. Try `iptables-translate`, it can help you with the bulk of the transition.

Comment: If you're here because you had issues with a script using `iptables` syntax (like me), then to avoid changing the script you can try `sudo update-alternatives --config iptables` to change which version is called by that name.

Answer (score 4):

`state` is deprecated, use

```
-m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED
```

instead of

```
-m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by `sudo modprobe ipt_owner`.

Comment: Your answer is a bit terse and could be improved by explaining the issue, i.e., the underlying cause of the problem and why your solution correctly would resolve it for the user in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after blacklisting kernel module `x_tables`, while still using `iptables-nft`. I thought `iptables-nft` would only need kernel module `nf_tables`, but it seems that it also depends on `x_tables` to recognize the matchnames (e.g. `-m state`, `-m limit`). From `lsmod` without blacklisting:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
x_tables               53248  4 xt_conntrack,nft_compat,xt_state,ip_tables
```

So, check if you did not blacklist kernel module `x_tables`, in one of the files in `/etc/modprobe.d/` for example.

Blacklisting `ip_tables` instead was no problem.

Versions: Debian 11.5, linux 5.10.149-2, iptables 1.8.7-1, nftables 0.9.8-3.1+deb11u1.